# Issue in QT 5.2.1 app in linking libquazip.so library during making .deb package for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: deb, qt5

I am making .deb package for the QT 5 .2.1 desktop app for ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. I have installed QT 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and made a demo app for the testing purpose in which I have used quazip library. During making the .deb package of the app I am getting the below issue.

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn’t find library libquazip.so.1 needed by debian/demoapp/usr/bin/DemoApp1 (ELF format: ‘elf64-x86-64’; RPATH: ‘’)
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: package could avoid a useless dependency if debian/demoapp/usr/bin/DemoApp1 was not linked against libz.so.1 (it uses none of the library’s symbols)
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot continue due to the error above
Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to use -l.
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/demoapp.substvars debian/demoapp/usr/bin/DemoApp1 returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary-predeb-IMPL/demoapp] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

When I copy the `libquazip.so.1` at the path `/usr/lib` in my machine then I got the below issue .

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/lib/libquazip.so.1 (used by debian/demoapp/usr/bin/DemoApp1)
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/demoapp.substvars debian/demoapp/usr/bin/DemoApp1 returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary-predeb-IMPL/demoapp] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

My CMakeLists.txt file as per below.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(DemoApp1)
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} “;/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake;”)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
include_directories(/home/manojpatidar/Manoj/Work/QT_WORK/Linux_Package/demoapp-1.0/lib/quazip-0.5.1/quazip)
link_directories(/home/manojpatidar/Manoj/Work/QT_WORK/Linux_Package/demoapp-1.0/lib/quazip-0.5.1)
add_executable(DemoApp1 main.cpp mainwindow.cpp moc_mainwindow.cpp mainwindow.ui)
target_link_libraries(DemoApp1 quazip z)
install(TARGETS DemoApp1 RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
qt5_use_modules(DemoApp1 Widgets)
```

My Debian control file is as per below .

```
Source: demoapp
Section: games
Priority: extra
Maintainer: Manoj Patidar 
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8.0.0), cmake, qtbase5-dev, cdbs
Standards-Version: 3.9.4

Package: demoapp
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: Description
Description will come here
```

I think I need to add some dependencies for `quazip` at the line `Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}`. Is there anything I have missed?

Comment: Can anyone please let me know how can I add quazip build dependency in debian control file at the line **Build-Depends:** and **Depends:** like **quazip-0.5.1 (>=0.5.1)** ? I am using quazip-0.5.1. I think I have missed to add this in control file.

Comment: Can anybody help ?

Comment: Try it, for build-depends it should be `libquazip0-dev`

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. But I have fixed my concern regarding unzip  by the alternative solution using /usr/bin/unzip process instead of using quazip.